# PHP: Valores nulos en foreach

Tags: php, ajax

No veo qué está fallando aquí, aunque debe de ser muy obvio:

```
var_dump($array_orden);

foreach($array_orden as $clave => $valor)
{   
    var_dump($valor);

    var_dump($valor->id_cancion);
    var_dump($valor->orden);
}
```

Lo que sale por la consola (en Network, es una llamada AJaX):

```
C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:17:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_cancion' => string '214' (length=3)
      'orden' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id_cancion' => string '212' (length=3)
      'orden' => string '2' (length=1)

C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:21:
array (size=2)
  'id_cancion' => string '214' (length=3)
  'orden' => string '1' (length=1)

C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:23:null
C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:24:null

C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:21:
array (size=2)
  'id_cancion' => string '212' (length=3)
  'orden' => string '2' (length=1)

C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:23:null
C:\wamp64\www\Recopilatorios\PHP\Web\MVC\ajax_reordenar_lista.php:24:null
```

¿Por qué `var_dump($valor);` da el resultado que espero pero `var_dump($valor->id_cancion);` y `var_dump($valor->orden);` dan nulo?

Comment: Por favor trata de proveer un [mcve]

Comment: No hay mucho más que decir: un array -con contenido- que entra en un foreach, `$valor` dentro del foreach también muestra contenido pero `$valor->id_cancion` o `$valor->orden` no. Ha de tratarse de algún problema de sintaxis, aunque no veo cuál.

Comment: Intentaste acceder como Arreglo? `$valor['id_cancion']` `$valor['orden']`

Comment: Pues ése era el problema. Desde que empecé con PHP OO no había vuelto a usar esa sintaxis porque siempre me daba error. Este array proviene directamente de jQuery, y no de uno de mis modelos PHP; supongo que por eso requiere la sintaxis procedimental y no la OO.

Comment: Si claro todo depende de como envíes los datos desde jQuery. En el primer `var_dump` puedes notar que llega todo en forma de Array size 2 y dentro array size 2

Comment: `$valor` sería un array, y la sintaxis para leer arrays es `$array['clave']`, pero tú estás usando la sintaxis para leer objetos que es `$objeto->propiedad`. Debes leer cada cosa como lo que es, si array, array, si objeto, objeto. O, a lo sumo, convertirlo si fuera necesario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código que expones `$valor` es un array, y la sintaxis para leer arrays es `$array['clave']`, pero tú estás usando la sintaxis para leer objetos que es `$objeto->propiedad`. Debes leer cada cosa como lo que es, si array, array, si objeto, objeto. O, a lo sumo, convertirlo si fuera necesario.

El `var_dump` te dice precisamente el tipo de lo que estás depurando. Veamos el código corregido:

```
$array_orden=array(
    array (
      'id_cancion' =>  '214',
      'orden' =>  '1'
    ),
    array (
      'id_cancion' =>  '212',
      'orden' =>  '2'
    )
);

foreach($array_orden as $clave => $valor)
{   
    var_dump($valor);

    var_dump($valor['id_cancion']);
    var_dump($valor['orden']);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  ["id_cancion"]=>
  string(3) "214"
  ["orden"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

string(3) "214"
string(1) "1"

array(2) {
  ["id_cancion"]=>
  string(3) "212"
  ["orden"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

string(3) "212"
string(1) "2"
```

El `var_dump` te dice siempre `array(2)` o sea, un array con dos elementos dentro. Si es un array, entonces debes usar la sintaxis `$array['clave']` para leerlo.

---

Veamos un ejemplo donde en vez de un array sería un objeto:

```
$array_orden=array(
    (object) array (
      'id_cancion' =>  '214',
      'orden' =>  '1'
    ),
    (object) array (
      'id_cancion' =>  '212',
      'orden' =>  '2'
    )
);

foreach($array_orden as $clave => $valor)
{   
    var_dump($valor);

    var_dump($valor->id_cancion);
    var_dump($valor->orden);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["id_cancion"]=>
  string(3) "214"
  ["orden"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

string(3) "214"
string(1) "1"

object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["id_cancion"]=>
  string(3) "212"
  ["orden"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}

string(3) "212"
string(1) "2"
```

Observa que ahora el `var_dump` te dice algo como esto: `object(stdClass)#1 (2)` o sea, un objeto, con dos propiedades. Como ya dijimos, si es un objeto se lee con la sintaxis `$objeto->propiedad`. Por eso aquí sí es posible el modo de lectura que intentabas al principio.